# Can I paste into an entire selection in an Access table?

Tags: ms-access

Access allows me to select several "cells" simultaneously.  To me, it seems intuitive that I should be able to paste a value into this entire selection at once, similar to Excel.  However, this does not work as I expect; I can only paste into the first selected "cell".

I know that I could perform an update query; however, this would take longer than just manually going to each individual "cell" and pasting, if all I need is to update 15 records or so.  I also know that I can go to Excel and create a range of 15 cells with the same value, then copy the Excel range, make my selection in Access, and then paste, and this works.  However, it seems unnecessarily tedious.

Is there any feature in Access that I am missing that would allow me to quickly and easily paste a value into an entire selection in Access?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in Access.

(And I think this is a good thing, a table isn't a spreadsheet, even if it looks similar.)

As you wrote, the workaround is to prepare and copy a range with identical size & data types in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can mark the *record selector* (far left) and press `Ctrl+V`